# Appstream - Upload docs from local to AppStream shared S3 bucket drive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-appstream

I'm working on an AWS Appstream 2.0 shared docs requirement.

I need to have shared drive for Appstream users to share the documents. Users should be able to upload the docs to Appstream instance from local drive and should be shared across \network path. And a custom app running in AppStream should be able to access this shared drives.

(I have tried FSx and AWS AD with domain join , but its not our requirement to have so many components.)

In order to fulfil this, Created a S3 bucket and Mounted as drive in Appstream, so that my instance can have shared path. But the problem is, how can I upload files to appstream's network drive( which was mounted) from local workspace.

[image]

1. Basically, I'll have to upload the docs from local to a shared folder (shared drive) to Appstream mounted drive which is S3. Please find the image below. Out the box it only allows me to upload to Temporary Folder / Home Folders, Usually files gets saved in APPstream S3 bucket in user profile. (in users/directory) which I don't want instead should get saved in Shared access.

[image]

2. How can I have AppStream end users upload the files to shared directory in S3 bucket, where users can access. (Instead of individual network profile)

In a NutShell, how to upload files from local workspace to Appstream's Mounted S3 drive? Out of the box it only allows me to upload only to - Home/Temporary Folders

The workaround I have is to write a bat script to sync Temporary folder & Mounted Drive. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native solution to use a S3 bucket as shared network drive. However there are 3rd party solutions out there that could work for you, eg. [CloudBerry Drive](https://www.msp360.com/drive.aspx).

Personally, I would prefer Amazon FSx for Windows File Server.